# What happens when you beat Bugdroid in the Fruit Ninja tournament?

Tags: android, fruit-ninja

At random times when I'm playing Fruit Ninja, I'm getting tournament challenges from Bugdroid. It's not part of the normal roster, and I can only play it when challenged.

[image: Bugdroid]

However, the challenge seems almost impossible to beat. Bugdroid almost always gets perfect combos, and snipes the neutral fruit with ridiculous speed.

Is there any reward for beating the challenge, or is it just for bragging rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally did it!

[image: "Please accept these tokens as a reward for your services"]

Nothing much happens, though. Bugdroid gives you **1000 Starfruit** for winning, and thanks you for your "input".

Answer (score -2):

I've managed to beat him a couple of times. There was no reward.

Comment: So, what happens? Just nothing? That's a bit disappointing.